# Found old paper shares of Motorola Inc that has since been broken up

Tags: stocks, shares

I found 36 physical shares of motorola inc from 1999. I know that since then the company has split up into a lot of subsidiaries/mergers.

Is there any to sell this physical stock or is it worthless? if not worthless, do you have any idea what the value is?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

In order to determine what has happened to Motorola, you need to look at any corporate actions that have occurred on the stock.

**CORPORATE ACTIONS**

Motorola Inc had the following corporate actions since 1999:

- Jun 2000: 3:1 Stock split (so your 36 shares became 108 shares)
- Dec 2004: 0.110415:1 Spinoff of Freescale Semiconductor Class B shares (i.e. 11.925 shares, with the fractional share paid as cash)
- Dec 2006: Freescale Semiconductor was taken over in an all-cash deal ($40/share).  So 11 shares * 40 = $440.
- Jan 2011: 1:8 Spinoff of Motorola Mobility.  You've now got 13.5 shares of Motorola Mobility (MMI).  Fractional shares paid in cash.
- Jan 2011: Motorola Inc changed name to Motorola Solutions Inc.  Symbol changed to MSI.
- Jan 2011: Reverse split 1:7.  Your 108 MSI shares become 15.43 shares (fractional amount would have been paid in cash)
- May 2012: Motorola Mobility taken over by Google in all cash deal ($40/share).
- 1999 to today: Motorola/Motorola Solutions paid/pay quarterly dividends.  The other spunoff companies never paid dividends.

Source: Internal databases at [Norgate Data](https://norgatedata.com)

**CURRENT VALUE**

- As of 19 July 2019, you'd have 15 MSI shares (close price was $168.91) so they're worth $2533.
- You're owed some of the fractional cash amounts from the various splits/spinoffs.
- You're owed $440 from the Freescale Semiconductor takeover
- You're owed $520 from the Motorola Mobility takeover
- You're owed around $350 in dividends from Motorola / Motorola Solutions

**HOW TO CLAIM**

You should contact the Investor Relations department of Motorola Solutions to figure out how to convert your physical shares and claim the other monies http://investors.motorolasolutions.com/

If you can, please report back on your progress as comments, so others can see what steps you needed to go through to claim your entitlements.

Comment: Can those spinoffs, takeovers, and dividends really be claimed retroactively? Do companies set up escrow accounts to implement corporate actions for shareholders who can't be contacted?

Comment: @nanoman - that would probably make an excellent new question.

Comment: @nanoman Generally yes, you can claim them. There is a limitations on claims older than 7 years if owners can't be traced.

Comment: So that's about £3500 richer in 9 hours! :-)

Comment: if I may ask, I also just found 10 EMC shares from 2001 and another 18 motorola shares from 1996. Do you know their value? I can't find anything online

Comment: Hi thelegened - ask both of those as separate questions.  Happy to answer, but it will take me a little while to research and respond.  Cheers, Richard.

Comment: hi richard, I asked the question here - thanks in advance https://money.stackexchange.com/q/111596/88246

Comment: you should specify that for all your trouble in researching this you are charging a 5% fee ;-)

Comment: I wish I was earning 5% on these answers!  For the record, Norgate Data doesn't deal with shares - we are just a data vendor with a rather extensive database.  I answer these questions to help out others and gain reputation.  Cheers, Richard.

Comment: @Michael: I thought about it too. Even 1% would be better than nothing. And nothing is what OP had before this answer.

Comment: @Owain depends how much was paid for them ;)